# How To read this Calligraphy?

Tags: meaning, calligraphy

Our DOJO is covered with slogans and proverbs. Often calligraphy that is not done by a highly trained person. I can translate most of them but a few are baffling. 
Some of the others read "kunren" "nintai" "ketsudanryoku" "kenson" and "Bukkyou". 
There are 4 of these panels that are apparently all to do with the 4 noble truths. The first one reads Bukkyou" - these are panels 2 and 3.  Your help and suggestions are most welcome.

[image: Second Noble Truth?]
[image: Third Noble Truth?]

Comment: The writings don't only contain some serious misunderstandings about kanji, but also don't seem to be Japanese. I managed to recognize two biblical personal names in **Chinese**: 約瑟 (Joseph) and 馬莉 (Mary).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about Chinese rather than Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Broccoli Forest, basically they are "Saint (First character seems to be 圣/聖) Joseph " and "Mary."

Japanese language used more of those Kanjis dated back though -- like 「アメリカ」 used to be 「亜墨利加」 in many of the historical documents in the Japanese town I have stayed, and they are not strictly speaking Japanese Kanjis, but translation adopted straightly from Chinese (Chinese sometimes also adopted Japanese translation directly, such as 権利).

Hope this provides more contexts...